# How to add an element and bind an event to it?

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation

I want to make a resize-directive. Therefore I want to create a new element (the resizer) and bind an event to it, but in my code the event is bind to the directive-rootElement:

```
elm.append('<div class="iwResizable__resizer"></div>').bind('mousedown', function ($event) {
                        startW = elm.prop('offsetWidth');
                        startH = elm.prop('offsetHeight');
                        initialMouseX = $event.clientX;
                        initialMouseY = $event.clientY;
                        $document.bind('mousemove', mousemove);
                        $document.bind('mouseup', mouseup);
                        $event.preventDefault();
                });
```

How can I bind the mousedown-event to my new div?

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1hIwijiFvfPOktRWNcjX?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not sure you're doing it in a very angular-way... have you seen [ng-mousedown](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMousedown)?

Comment: I placed this in the link-block of the directive because I need access to the 'element' attribute. Is this possible in the controller too? Sorry, I´m new in angular. @glepretre

Comment: DOM manipulations must be in a directive indeed but I don't know much  about the perimeter of your resize directive, could you create a simple fiddle/plunker?

Comment: Okay, here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1hIwijiFvfPOktRWNcjX?p=preview)  @glepretre

Comment: Good, you should edit your question to add it ;) That seems a bit overkill, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Now it resizes when I click somewhere on the div, but it shoult only work if I click on the blue triangle @glepretre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using jQuery (which you don't seem to), you should do the instantiation/binding and the appending in different statements:

```
var resizer = angular.element('<div class="myResizable__resizer"></div>')
                     .bind('mousedown', function ($event) {...});
elm.append(resizer);
```

If you were using jQuery, you could use the **[`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)** function (which is **[not implemented](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)** in JQLite), you could do it like this:

```
$('<div class="myResizable__resizer"></div>').appendTo(elm).bind(...);
```